# Get Text of UILabel with lineBreakMode

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

I want to get the visible Text of UILabel that received lineBreakMode and numberOflines in Nib file.
Or NSarray of the text (visible and not visible), each row is row in label..

Can Someone help me?
Thank you..

Edit:

In xcode I have UILablel, I create label in a nib file.
In the UILabel properties, I determine the number of line and also LineBreakMode.

Example: In the phonebook there is 1 number of line, and I have a very long name so I just see the begining of the name with 3 dots after(if the name in the phonebook is longer then the frame of the label) I think this is LineBreakMode:trunk property.
the name is:Rebecca. so we will see Reb...

If it's LineBreakMode:wrap so the 3 dots will not apper but we will see less from the name, etc.

What I need is to know what is the visible text.
if the text is Rebecca, but on screen I see Reb... so I need only Reb..., and not Rebecca.
if it's not trunc, so I need Reb without the 3 dots, and etc.

According to the LineBreakMode property and number of line, I just need to know the visible text that is on screen.

Hope it's more clear now..

Comment: Can you please explain more what are you looking for and where you are getting error or crash

Comment: Rebecca welcome to stack overflow community. Please read [FAQ] so that you can improve your question quality

Comment: She wants the text with the line breaks from the label. So for example, if the text is broken up three times, she would like for it to return the text with two \n in the text. Or if the text is being truncated it's only a UI thing and the text in the label is still the full text, but she wants the text as is would appear if truncated. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you runmad!!